# Web Intelligence report scheduled as a CSV generates a WID

Tags: business-objects

We are running Business Objects XI 3.1 Service Pack 3 and are experiencing an issue scheduling files as a CSV.

Although all the relevant options are set when scheduling to disk or via email, the report is delivered as a .WID instead.

Does anyone have a fix for this, or can confirm that it is fixed in version 4?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: We were on SP3 for a long time and did not have this problem.  We are on SP5 now and still ok.

Comment: Oops; hit enter too quick...   I just tested it on SP5.  Does PDF/Excel export work ok?

Comment: Hi Joe. PDF and Excel work fine, it is only when scheduling as CSV it seems to default back to WID. I think it may have something to do with the configuration of the Adaptive Job Server, but can't prove it yet. Thanks!